# Building workspace has encountered a prob in eclipse for Android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, adt

[image]

Hi guys!

I have been stuck on this problem for 3 days now. The reason why I have been stuck for so long is that I have been trying to fix the problem but not succeeded.. :(

So I'm trying to set up the environment for developing apps for Android and I have got this far (See image ). After I have downloaded the Android SDK and installed it, installed the ADT plugin for Eclipse and downloaded the latest SDK tools and platforms using the SDK Manager in Eclipse I still get this problem.. I have also tried to download a different version of Eclipse and tried to do all this steps 10 times or more but still get the same problem..

I am following this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html 
So I have done every they say but still I get this problem.

I have deleted the workspace folder and tried to use a different folder still same problem occurs. 
P.S I have tried to go to "Android Tools->Fix project properties" with right-click but still nothing..

So please if you know how to fix this problem, help me :( and i have looked at all the stackoverflow posts about this but have not solved the problem :(

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by NOT using eclipse!! Instead I installed Android SDK on NetBeans! and it works fine :)

Answer (score -1):

Hey don't know if you have figured this out by now. But here is post I made for with all error messages being logged with fix.

http://hilifedev.blogspot.com/p/android.html

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks dude! I'll try this later on and add a comment here if it helps  :)